# libv8 fails on installation using jruby

Tags: jruby, libv8

I am trying to bundle install a sample rails 4 app and I am running into the following problem. libv8 fails on installation using jruby 1.7.18.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /home/kingslee/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.18/bin/jruby extconf.rb 
/home/kingslee/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.18/lib/ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:14: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /home/kingslee/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.18/lib/native/include/ruby/ruby.h


Gem files will remain installed in /home/kingslee/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@app/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/kingslee/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18@app/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.7), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess rubyrhino should solve the problem - https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues/131